# Using MapIndexed only at certain elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

`MapIndexed` is a very handy built-in function.  Suppose that I have the following list, called `list`:

```
list = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

I can use `MapIndexed` to map an arbitrary function `f` across `list`:

```
{f[10, {1}], f[20, {2}], f[30, {3}], f[40, {4}]}
```

where the second argument to `f` is the part specification of each element of the list.

But, now, what if I would like to use `MapIndexed` only at certain elements?  Suppose, for example, that I want to apply `MapIndexed` to only the second and third elements of `list`, obtaining the following:

```
{10, f[20, {2}], f[30, {3}], 40}
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in "`MapAtIndexed`", as far as I can tell.  What is a simple way to accomplish this?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`If` does the job and is simple enough:

```
MapIndexed[If[2 ≤ First@#2 ≤ 3, f[#, #2], #] &, list]
(* {10, f[20, {2}], f[30, {3}], 40} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way, using `MapIndexed`'s functionality, like [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5)'s:

```
mapAtIndexed[f_, expr_, pos_, levelspec_: 1, opts : OptionsPattern[MapIndexed]] :=
 Module[{f0},
  f0[x_, p : Alternatives @@ pos] := f[x, p];
  f0[x_, _] := x;
  MapIndexed[f0, expr, levelspec, opts]
  ]
```

OP's example:

```
mapAtIndexed[g, list, {{2}, {3}}]
(* {10, g[20, {2}], g[30, {3}], 40} *)
```

Multiple levels (pay attention to the `{2}`):

```
mapAtIndexed[f, Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}],
             {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}}, 2]
(* {{11, f[12, {1, 2}], f[13, {1, 3}]}, 
    f[{f[21, {2, 1}], 22, 23}, {2}],
    {31, f[32, {3, 2}], 33},
    {41, 42, f[43, {4, 3}]}} *)
```

Heads, too:

```
mapAtIndexed[f, list, {{2}, {4}, {0}}, Heads -> True]
(* f[List, {0}][10, f[20, {2}], 30, f[40, {4}]] *)
```

---

**Alternate solution**

In this we have to ensure `f` is mapped at the lower levels first, using `Reverse @ Sort @ ...`, since we're not using `Map`.  However it's quite a bit faster.

```
mapAI2[f_, expr_, pos_] := Module[{e0 = expr},
  (e0[[Sequence @@ #]] = f[e0[[Sequence @@ #]], #]) & /@ Reverse @ Sort @ pos;
  e0
  ]
```

Example

```
mapAI2[f, Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}],
       {{1, 2}, {3, 0}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}}]
(* {{11, f[12, {1, 2}], f[13, {1, 3}]},
    f[{f[21, {2, 1}], 22, 23}, {2}], 
    f[List, {3, 0}][31, f[32, {3, 2}], 33],
    {41, 42, f[43, {4, 3}]}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a form similar to Kuba's approach:

```
mapAtIndexed[f_, list_, pos_] :=
  ReplacePart[list, # :> f[list[[Sequence @@ #]], #] & /@ pos];
```

A pure pattern version:

```
mapAtIndexed[f_, list_, pos_] :=
  ReplacePart[list,
   i : (Alternatives @@ pos) :> f[list[[Sequence @@ i]], i]];
```

And I assume you're familiar with `Position`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure one can improve following solution

```
SetAttributes[mapIndexedAt, HoldRest];
mapIndexedAt[f_, list_, pos_] := Do[list = MapAt[f[#, pos[[i]]] &, list, pos[[i]]]
                                    , {i, Length@pos}]

l = {1, 1, 1, 1};
mapIndexedAt[(#1 + #2) &, l, {2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4, 1}
> ```

It does not look good but at least it is not scanning through the list.

A little variation with `Fold`:

```
f = #1 + #2 &
Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> f[#1[[#2]], #2]] &, l, {2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**Level one version**

This is an adaptation of amr's answer (based on Kuba's answer)

```
mapAtLevOneIndexed[f_, list_, pos_] :=     
 ReplacePart[list, 
  Inner[Rule[#, f[#2, #]] &, pos, Part[list, pos], List]]
```

Example

```
mapAtLevOneIndexed[f, {1, 2, 6, 7}, {2, 3}]
```

-> {1, f[2, 2], f[6, 3], 7}

In the case you work at level one, I think the most convenient way to enter a position is just a single integer. Also I think that is the most convenient way for the position to occur in `f`, but this makes it a little different from `MaxIndexed`.

This may be a case where `Thread` is faster than `Inner`, maybe I will check later. The idea here is that we use both `Part` and `ReplacePart` both only once, to speed things up. This use of `Part` only works on level one. Despite this I don't think it is faster than rm-rf's answer, which is my favorite. Maybe it can be faster if the positions at which we want to "mapindex" are very sparse.

**Deeper level version**

Of course you can let `Extract` do the job of `Part` here and make it work on deeper levels. Below I use `Thread` just convenience, as `Inner` did not deal with lists of lists as I want. I do not answer which one is faster.

Deeper level version:

```
mapAtIndexed[f_, list_, pos_] :=
 ReplacePart[list, 
  Thread[Unevaluated[
    Rule[#, f[#2 // First, #]] &[pos, Extract[list, pos]]]]]
```

**Examples**

```
mapAtIndexed[f, {{{1}}, 2}, {{1, 1}}]
```

-> {{f[{1}, {1, 1}]}, 2}

```
mapAtIndexed[f, {{{1}}, 2}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2}}]
```

-> {{{f[1, {1, 1, 1}]}}, f[1, {2}]}

Here you have to be careful to enter the positions in the form `{pos1, pos2}`, rather than just `pos1`, but that can be easily overcome.

Comment: Thanks for investigation and extension :) `ReplacePart` based solutions seem to be ideal for this since they are not scanning through the list.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I like `ReplacePart` in theory, but it may be slower in practice than you might expect, especially for big lists. I suppose in theory `Extract` also does not scan the entire list. I would very much like it if there was a built in function that did what my myAtIndexed did, but for a given head inside the `Thread`. Maybe I will elaborate on this later in a new post :).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
list = {10, 20, 30, 40};

newlist =list/.{a_,b_,c_,d_}:>{a,f[b,2],f[c,3],d}
```

In this way, you give a lable to any element of your list, and using `:>`, you can map some other function on some of elements of your list. In the above code for example, a and d are not changed, while the second and thord elements are changed.