# Map function on the specified location

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, list, List /@ {4, 9, 2}];
MapAt[Style[#, Green] &, %, List /@ {3, 5, 7}];
MapAt[Style[#, Blue] &, %, List /@ {8, 1, 6}]
```

[image]

I am sure there is a better way do this, could you give any better ideas?

Comment: The ["MapAtIndexed" question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28532/using-mapindexed-only-at-certain-elements-of-a-list) is tangentially related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's no formula or pattern to the colors, then you have to somehow manually indicate how to style each part.  Here are a couple of ways to do that using [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) to encode key/value pairs (in the form `part -> style`):

```
styleRules1 = {{4, 9, 2} -> Red, {3, 5, 7} -> Green, {8, 1, 6} -> Blue};

styleRules2 = {4 | 9 | 2 -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 3 | 5 | 7 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
    8 | 1 | 6 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]};
```

Here's a function that can take a list of such styling rules and apply them to the parts:

```
stylePart[expr_, rules_] := 
 ReplacePart[expr, 
  styleRules /. HoldPattern@Rule[alt_, color_] :> (i : alt :> Style[expr[[i]], color])
  ]
```

Examples

```
stylePart[list, Flatten[Thread /@ styleRules1]]

stylePart[list, styleRules2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here is another way to use such rules:

```
saStyles = SparseArray[styleRules2, Length@list];

styleIt[x_, 0] := x;
styleIt[x_, style_] := Style[x, style];
MapThread[styleIt, {list, saStyles}]
```

Comment: I see that you are using `Alternatives` as I did in my first code.  Unless this has been universally optimized in v9 (I know it has been optimized in `DeleteCases` for example) this will slow in proportion to the number of alternatives.  I see that you used `SparseArray` before I did so credit where it's due.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I assumed, since the question is about styling, that speed on a very large set was not an important issue.  `Alternatives` seemed a quite readable alternative way to write the styling rules.  (I meant that `Alternatives` was an alternative form of input, and I've edited the answer to make clearer, I hope.)

Comment: Okay, I see it more clearly now.  By the way, I do not assume that this question is about styling, but rather that `Style` was merely a nice illustration.  This is why I did not write my answer to work with a list of colors but rather a list of functions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yours is a more interesting interpretation.  When I've done such things on a larger scale, the positions have been determined by properties of the data and I've used the properties instead.

Answer (score 9):

With these definitions:

```
list=CharacterRange["a","n"];
colorRules={{4,9,2}-> Red,{3,5,7}-> Green,{8,1,6}-> Blue};
```

Here is one option using Fold

```
colorize[list_,colorRule_]:=MapAt[Style[#,colorRule[[1]]]&,list,List /@ colorRule[[2]]]
Fold[colorize,list,colorRules]
```

[image]

Here is another using `Rules` with `MapIdexed`

```
rule=Dispatch@Flatten@Join[Thread/@colorRules,{_-> ""}];
MapIndexed[Style[#,#2[[1]]/.rule]&,list]
```

[image]

Comment: I like `_ -> Identity` :)

Answer (score 7):

I think the most straightforward way is to use `Switch` and `MapIndexed`:

```
colorF[l_, {i_}] := Switch[i,
   4 | 9 | 2, Style[l, Red],
   3 | 5 | 7, Style[l, Green],
   8 | 1 | 6, Style[l, Blue],
   _, l
   ];
MapIndexed[colorF, list]
```

Another possibility is `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list,
 {i_ /; MatchQ[i, 4 | 9 | 2] :> Style[list[[i]], Red],
  i_ /; MatchQ[i, 3 | 5 | 7] :> Style[list[[i]], Green],
  i_ /; MatchQ[i, 8 | 1 | 6] :> Style[list[[i]], Blue]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

This question looks like fun.  Too bad I missed out on the early action.  I don't have much time but two ideas came to mind.  The first was assignments to `Part` which I believe ssch already did.  The second is creating a list if functions and then using `Inner` and `Compose` as I did for [Map a function across a list conditionally](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784/121).

```
fns = Function /@ Thread@Style[#, {Red, Green, Blue}];

pos = {{4, 9, 2}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 1, 6}};

fns2 = SparseArray[Join @@ Thread /@ Thread[pos -> fns], Length@list, Identity];

Inner[Compose, fns2, list, List]
```

I'll be back later to refine this and add comparative timings.

---

#### Update #1

I changed my code above to eliminate `Alternatives` which, at least in version 7, causes a considerable slow-down when applied to a large number of elements.  I knew this, but I was in a hurry.  I have replaced it with a double-`Thread` approach that scales better.

Nevertheless this `SparseArray` construct is slower than assignments to `Part`, which doesn't surprise me.   I could use `Part` assignments to build the function list that is passed to `Inner` but then there is little reason I can see not to use the method directly.  `Part` assignment is a [favorite method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) of mine anyway, so here is my variation of the `Part` assignment method ssch already posted:

```
mapAtParts[expr_, fns_List, pos_List] /;
  Length[fns] == Length[pos] && Max[pos] <= Length[expr] :=
    Module[{w = expr},
      MapThread[w[[#]] = #2 /@ w[[#]]; &, {pos, fns}];
      w
    ]
```

Example:

```
mapAtParts[
  CharacterRange["a", "n"],
  Function /@ Thread @ Style[#, {Red, Green, Blue}],
  {{4, 9, 2}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 1, 6}}
]
```

[image]

**Note:** as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/121) in the section **"We're not done yet"** if the functions are Listable it will be more efficient to use that, i.e. `w[[#]] = #2 @ w[[#]]; &`.

Comment: another answer that has taught me a lot...SparseArray and Compose wonderful.

Answer (score 5):

```
MapIndexed[{First@#2, #} &,  CharacterRange["a",  "n"]] /. 
 {{id : Alternatives @@ {4, 9, 2}, el_} :> Style[el, Red],
  {id : Alternatives @@ {3, 5, 7}, el_} :> Style[el, Green],
  {id : Alternatives @@ {8, 1, 6}, el_} :> Style[el, Blue],
  {_, el_} -> el
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

By copying the list and then repeatedly replacing part of it:

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
result = list;
result[[{4, 9, 2}]] = Style[#, Red] & /@ result[[{4, 9, 2}]];
result[[{3, 5, 7}]] = Style[#, Green] & /@ result[[{3, 5, 7}]];
result[[{8, 1, 6}]] = Style[#, Blue] & /@ result[[{8, 1, 6}]];
result
(* result is now same as question output *)
```

This could be put in a function to save some typing:

```
MapAtMany::usage = "MapAtMany[{{f1, {i1, j1, ...}}, {f2, {i2, j2, ...}}, ...}, expr]";

MapAtMany[fpart_, expr_] := Module[{res = expr},
   Scan[
    (res[[ #[[2]] ]] = #[[1]] /@ res[[ #[[2]] ]]) &
    , fpart];
   res];

list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
fpart = {
   {Style[#, Red] &, {4, 9, 2}},
   {Style[#, Green] &, {3, 5, 7}},
   {Style[#, Blue] &, {8, 1, 6}}};

MapAtMany[fpart, list]
```

`Fold` can also be used so you don't have to refer to `%` for each successive function:

```
Fold[
 MapAt[#2[[1]], #1, Transpose@{#2[[2]]}] &,
 list,
 fpart
 ]
```

Although tests suggest that the `Fold` method is much slower and worse at scaling.

Comment: This is my favorite method and you have my vote, but IMHO you should not be using `Block` here.  Instead use `Module`.  I used to abuse `Block` a lot before people like Leonid showed me the error of my ways.  Should your list contain the Symbol `res` you will create a recursion; a simple example: `expr = {1, 2, x};
Block[{x = expr}, x]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the feedback, that hadn't crossed my mind. I'll think twice before autopiloting `Block` everywhere

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straightforward way using a `Table` where you make the list and the colors, and then match them.

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
Table[Style[list[[ii]], color[[Mod[ii, Length[color]] + 1]]], {ii, 1, Length[list]}]
```

[image]

If you wish to specify the colors manually, that's easy too

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
color = {Black, Red, Green, Blue};
locations = {2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
Table[Style[list[[ii]], color[[locations[[ii]]]]], {ii, 1, Length[list]}]
```

[image]

Here's a way that bypasses the `Table` and uses `MapThread` instead. You can choose the colors in `col` manually, by algorithm, or choose them randomly:

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
cols = RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green, Black}, Length[list]];    
MapThread[Style[#1, #2] &, {list, cols}]
```

Comment: @Murta -- thanks, the index is now fixed.

Comment: You can avoid index if you want using `Style[#, color[[Mod[#2[[1]], 3] + 1]]] &~MapIndexed~list`

Comment: The OP's example is not a repeating pattern.  That would have been a duplicate of [(3858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121).  Can you adapt your answer to handle arbitrary positions?

Comment: Incidentally it will be simpler to use `Inner`, but you're then recreating my (first) answer: `Inner[Style[#, color[[#2]]] &, list, locations, List]`

Comment: +1 for repeated updates to address my concerns. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A simple straightforward way for 1D lists (with non-continuous style associations):

```
list = Join[CharacterRange["a", "n"], {"Input", "MSG", Blue, Italic}]
color = {{4, 9, 2} -> Red, {12, 5, 7} -> Green, {8, 1, 6} -> Blue};

rules = ReplacePart[{} & /@ list, Flatten[color /. x_Rule :> Thread@x]];

Grid[{list}, ItemStyle -> {rules}]
MapThread[Style, {list, rules}]
```

[image]

Comment: Consider also `Join @@ Thread /@ color` in place of `Flatten[color /. x_Rule :> Thread@x]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "n"];
```

Here is how I would do it. First I would define a function to make a set of substitution rules for any set of indices and any given color.

```
makeRules[vars : {_Symbol ..}, 
    indices : {_Integer?Positive ..}, 
    color : (_RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue)] := 
  Map[Rule[vars[[#]], Style[vars[[#]], color]] &, indices]
```

Next I would generate the full set of rules needed for the whole list of symbols.

```
fullRules = Flatten[{
   makeRules[list, {4, 9, 2}, Red],
   makeRules[list, {3, 5, 7}, Green],
   makeRules[list, {8, 1, 6}, Blue]}]
```

Finally I would apply the rules to the given list.

```
list /. fullRules
```

[image: coloredSymbols.png]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the variety:

```
fun[list_, pos_, colors_] :=
 Module[
  {styles},
  styles = Function[{x}, Style[x, #]] & /@ colors;
  list /. 
   Flatten[Thread /@ 
     MapThread[#1 -> #2 /@ #1 &, {list[[#]] & /@ pos, styles}]]
  ]
```

Then

```
fun[list, {{4, 9, 2}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 1, 6}}, {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

yields the same result.

**EDIT**

Noting Mr. Wizard's correction and mainly as (my own) learning opportunity the following is essentially one of Mr. Wizard's approaches slightly different but mapping functions to positions not elements.

```
func[list_, pos_, col_] :=
 Module[
  {l, el, styles, rules},
  l = Length[list];
  styles = Function[{x}, Style[x, #]] & /@ col;
  rules = Flatten[Thread /@ MapThread[Rule[#1, #2] &, {pos, styles}]];
  el = ReplacePart[Table[Identity, {l}], rules];
  MapThread[Compose, {el, list}]
  ]
```

Then

```
func[list, {{4, 9, 2}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 1, 6}}, {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

works

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work quite right.  It will only work correctly if all the elements of `list` are unique, as your replacements are done by pattern rather than position.

Comment: thanks, point taken...another learning opportunity