# Combining MapAt and MapIndexed

Tags: functional-style

The very last example in the documentation for [MapAt](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html?q=MapAt&lang=en) is:

> MapAt applies f repeatedly if a part is mentioned repeatedly:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= MapAt[f, {a, b, c, d}, {{1}, {3}, {1}}]
>
> Out[1]= {f[f[a]], b, f[c], d}
> ```

So f is applied twice to the first element.

I have a problem in which f takes an additional arguments which should be different in the first and second invocations. Any ideas on how to do this?

If a `MapAtIndexed` function existed, I could do something like this:

```
d = {{1, "x"}, {3, "w"}, {1, "q"}};

MapAtIndexed[f[#, Extract[d, #2]] &, {a, b, c, d}, List /@ First /@ d]
```

And the output would be:

```
{f[f[a, "x"], "q"], b, f[c, "w"], d}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your output be {f[f[a, "x"], "q"], b, f[c, "w"], {{1, "x"}, {3, "w"}, {1, "q"}}} since you have defined d?

Comment: duplicate? :[Using MapIndexed only at certain elements of a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28532/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {a, b, c, d};
app = {{1, "x"}, {3, "w"}, {1, "q"}};
Fold[MapAt[f[#, u] & /. u -> #2[[2]], #1, #2[[1]]] &, list, app]

(* {f[f[a, "x"], "q"], b, f[c, "w"], d}*)
```

Or perhaps:

```
r = list
(r[[#1]] = f[r[[#1]], #2]) & @@@ app; r
(* {f[f[a, "x"], "q"], b, f[c, "w"], d} *)
```

Comment: @gus muchas de nadas :)